# my widget math formula doesn't calculate correctly

Tags: algorithm, widget

I have a question which may not be your area of expertise but I was trying to help out a friend on their site by making a numerology calculator that would calculate someones birthday, or life path number.  Birthday january 13, 1970. Lifepath is 1+(1+3)+(1+9+7+0)=13   1+3=4 so 4 is the number i'm looking for.  This is the formula I used Mod(Mod(n,45),9), n=[//math:${input1}//].  And that works on every birthday except one that is supposed to end in 9 in which case it says the lifepath number is 0.  Any ideas? One of our users bday is May 1, 1965 which is a 9 and it returns 0 as do all the combos i tried that equal 9. And here it is on the site.http://www.kryschendo.com/numerology_reports.html

Comment: Not sure what language you're using, but could you just do something like `if (value == 0){value = 9;}` at the end?

Comment: "1+(1+3)+(1+9+7+0)=13"; er, you need to either go back to basic maths or rephrase the question correctly.

Comment: Tried it like this and it still returning 0 Mod(Mod(n,45),9 Mod((n-1),9) + 1, If (value == 0 {value = 9;}), n=[//math:${input1}//]  Thanks for the suggestion, let me know if you think of anything else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if I'm understanding your example, it should be:

```
1+(1+3)+(1+9+7+0)=22
2+2=4
```

Try this:

```
 Mod((n-1),9) + 1, n=[//math:${input1}//]
```

Comment: Sorry- I meant 22. I accidentally typed the date again. Anyway- I added that formula and the same thing happened.  This is the first time I've tried to make a widget so there may be something I'm doing wrong that's not the formula? I have no idea....

Comment: The widget on your linked page still shows me the old formula, did you update that?  ((511965)%45)%9 = 0 but (511965 - 1)%9 + 1 = 9  - That formula should work.

Comment: Mod(Mod(n,45),9 ((511965)%45)%9 = 0 but (511965 - 1)%9 + 1 = 9), n=[//math:${input1}//]  Is this correct?  It's not on my linked page, it's just in the widget builder+

Comment: I was just giving example calculations.  The widget should just be:  Mod((n-1),9) + 1, n=[//math:${input1}//]